# What is difference between гроссмейстер-многоходовщик and simply гроссмейстер?

Tags: значения, терминология

What is difference between the terms гроссмейстер-многоходовщик and simply гроссмейстер?

Answer (score 4):

Гроссмейстер (нем. Großmeister «большой мастер») - высшее шахматное звание.

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B)

Официального звания "гроссмейстер-многоходовщик" не существует. **Многоходовщик** - это слово не из официального, а из разговорного стиля речи. Так называют человека со стратегическим складом ума, умеющего просчитывать свои действия на много "ходов" вперёд. И это качество совсем не обязательно имеет отношение к шахматам.

The official title of "grandmaster-многоходовщик" does not exist. **Многоходовщик**  - the word is not official and colloquial style of speech. So call a person with a strategic mind, able to recognize their actions on a lot of "moves" forward. And this quality does not necessarily has to do with chess.

Comment: Скорее "многоходовщик" вообще не имеет отношения к шахматам. Любой более-менее  серьёзный любитель этой игры считает на несколько ходов вперёд. Шахматный гроссмейстер сильнее перворазрядника не тем, что он считает на большее количество ходов вперёд (зачастую с точностью наоборот), а тем, что ему известно больше типовых позиций и исключений из них.